# Camel PGP Decryption fails when armored is false

Tags: java, apache-camel, bouncycastle, pgp

I have created a simple demo using Camel in order to encrypt/decrypt a PGP encrytion based file. The code is shown below.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.converter.crypto.PGPDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class PGPEncryptor {
    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PGPEncryptor.class);
    final String originalPath = "pgp/original";
    final String encryptedPath = "pgp/encrypted";
    final String decryptedPath = "pgp/decrypted";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            PGPEncryptor pgp = new PGPEncryptor();
            pgp.runEncryption();
            pgp.runDecryption();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    private void runEncryption() throws Exception {

        CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();

        ctx.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {

                PGPDataFormat encryptFormat = new PGPDataFormat();

                encryptFormat.setKeyFileName("file:keys/pubring.gpg");
                encryptFormat.setKeyUserid("XXXXX");
                encryptFormat.setArmored(true);
                // TODO setting armored to false (which is default) fails?

                from("file:" + originalPath + "?noop=true&charset=utf-8")
                        .marshal(encryptFormat)
                        .to("file:" + encryptedPath + "?charset=utf-8");
            }
        });

        ctx.start();

        // Maybe sleep a little here
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        ctx.stop();

        try {
            ctx.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    private void runDecryption() throws Exception {

        CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();

        camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

            public void configure() throws Exception {

                PGPDataFormat decryptFormat = new PGPDataFormat();

                decryptFormat.setKeyFileName("file:keys/secring.gpg");
                decryptFormat.setKeyUserid("XXXXX");
                decryptFormat.setPassword("XXXX");
                decryptFormat.setArmored(false);

                from("file:" + encryptedPath + "?noop=true&charset=utf-8")
                        .log("message  ${headers}")
                        .unmarshal(decryptFormat)
                        .to("file:" + decryptedPath + "?charset=utf-8");
            }
        });

        camelContext.start();
        // Maybe sleep a little here
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        camelContext.stop();

        try {
            camelContext.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

If `encryptFormat.setArmored(true);` is set to true the files from original folder are encrypted decrypted.
If armored is set to false or not set since it is **default** the
decryption fails with :

**If the file is signed by someone else with my public key (i.e read directly from my encrypted folder)**

```
java.io.EOFException: premature end of stream in PartialInputStream
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream$PartialInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:244)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343)
```

or if the file is encrytpted by the demo code using armor false

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The input message body has an invalid format. The PGP decryption/verification processor expects a sequence of PGP packets of the form (entries in brackets are optional and ellipses indicate repetition, comma represents  sequential composition, and vertical bar separates alternatives): Public Key Encrypted Session Key ..., Symmetrically Encrypted Data | Sym. Encrypted and Integrity Protected Data, (Compressed Data,) (One Pass Signature ...,) Literal Data, (Signature ...,)
    at org.apache.camel.converter.crypto.PGPKeyAccessDataFormat.getFormatException(PGPKeyAccessDataFormat.java:491)
    at org.apache.camel.converter.crypto.PGPKeyAccessDataFormat.getDecryptedData(PGPKeyAccessDataFormat.java:437)
    at org.apache.camel.converter.crypto.PGPKeyAccessDataFormat.unmarshal(PGPKeyAccessDataFormat.java:372)
    at org.apache.camel.support.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:76)
```

I have exported the keys to the older format since my keybox file named pubring.kbx using

```
gpg --export > pubring.gpg
gpg --export-secret-keys > secring.gpg
```

Is there some other configuration i am missing? Since my requirement is armored to by false. I am using latest camel with BC 1.76.